# Example to create sqlalchemy.create_engine object using dsn?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, odbc, drivers

I am trying to connect one of my remote database using odbc driver which is configured using DSN. But I did not find related parameters to create_engine object.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server:

You need to first create a DSN object to use. Go to `Start»Settings»Control Panel»Administrative Tools»Data Sources`

Open System DSN and add a new DSN. It will give you a list of databases for which you can create a DSN. Select one and and proceed with the steps. Give a name to the DSN (by which you will refer to it later) and the database server name to which you want to connect to. Click [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/configuring-odbc-win/) for more detailed steps.

`SQL Alchemy`

For using this DSN you created with your program you need to use the following steps:

```
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://SQLTEST')
saconn = engine.connect()
```

Now you have the engine object `saconn`. This can be used for performing your queries on the database.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the classic "//DSNSTRING" method didn't work with SQL Server.  From my environment (Python + MSSQL); the below worked:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:password@DSNSTRING")
```

Hope that helps